# How to sum rows based on multiple conditions and replace it in the dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate, row

R beginner here in need of some help. I have this dataframe:

```
dat<-data.frame(Name=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                Score=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                Frequency=c(9,11,10,5,5,3,7,10,5,5,20,3,3,2,2))
```

[image]

And I want to sum the frequencies of rows with scores 2-3 and 4-5 by name, and rename the scores High (score 1), Medium (scores 2-3) or Low (scores 4-5). Basically my dataframe should look like this:

[image]

Is there a more straightforward way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach.

First, create `Category` based on the `Score` using `cut`:

```
dat$Category <- cut(dat$Score, 
                    breaks = c(1, 2, 4, 5), 
                    labels = c("High", "Medium", "Low"), 
                    include.lowest = T, 
                    right = F)
```

Then you can `aggregate` based on both `Name` and `Category` to get the final result:

```
aggregate(Frequency ~ Name + Category, data = dat, sum)
```

**Output**

```
  Name Category Frequency
1    A     High         9
2    B     High         3
3    C     High        20
4    A   Medium        21
5    B   Medium        17
6    C   Medium         6
7    A      Low        10
8    B      Low        10
9    C      Low         4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first use `case_when` to convert the score to right class en then `group_by` and `sumamrise` your data like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(Score = case_when(Score == 1 ~ "High",
                           Score %in% c(2,3) ~ "Medium",
                           TRUE ~ "Low")) %>%
  group_by(Name, Score) %>%
  summarise(Frequency = sum(Frequency))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#> # Groups:   Name [3]
#>   Name  Score  Frequency
#>   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 A     High           9
#> 2 A     Low           10
#> 3 A     Medium        21
#> 4 B     High           3
#> 5 B     Low           10
#> 6 B     Medium        17
#> 7 C     High          20
#> 8 C     Low            4
#> 9 C     Medium         6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! However, when using this I only get this output: ``Frequency 
1       100``

(Basically a 1x1 dataframe with just Frequency as the column name and 100 in the row).

Comment: Hi @maplesyrup123, are your scores numeric or characters, so which type?

Comment: They are numeric... Though I tried to change them to characters and the result is still the same